# Audio API Suitable for multi channel playback in windows

Tags: c, api, audio

I am researching a project in which I need to playback simultaneously a multi-track audio source. ( >30 mono channels ) The audio on all channels needs to start simultaneously and be sustained for hours of playback.

What is the best audio API to use for this? WDM and ASIO have come up in my searches. I will be using a [MOTU PCI Audio interface](http://www.motu.com/products/pciaudio/) to get this many channels. The channels show up as normal audio channels in the host PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASIO is definitely the way to go about this.  It will keep everything in sync properly, with low latency, and is the defacto industry standard way to do it.  Any pro audio interfaces supports ASIO, and for interfaces that don't, [there is a wrapper](http://www.asio4all.com/) that is capable of syncing multiple devices.

Comment: Thanks @Brad, Any suggestions for resources on ASIO?

Comment: If the licensing is appropriate for your use, you should check out BASS at http://www.un4seen.com/.  I've used it for a couple .NET applications, and it was quite solid.  There is a C/C++ API as well, and I would imagine it is also easy to use.  The official ASIO SDK can be obtained from Steinberg at http://www.steinberg.net/en/company/developer.html